# Dajngo авторизация и csrf_token

Tags: django

У меня есть шаблон index.html, и шаблоны blog.html, page.html итд.. которые его наследуют(сам шаблон index.html напрямую нигде не вызывается). В шаблоне index.html у меня есть форма авторизации

```
<form method="POST" action="/login/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    # Тут поля логин пароль и кнопка отпрваить
</form>
```

Как сделать так что бы csrf_token подставлялся сам по себе? что бы при выводе шаблона не приходилось его подставлять?
Если не делать вот так

```
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
 c = {}
c.update(csrf(request))
# ... view code here
return render_to_response("template.html", c)
```

То получаю ошибку

**Forbidden (403)**
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

**Help**
Reason given for failure:
    CSRF token missing or incorrect.

Comment: Ну так он и подставляется автоматически! Не вижу никакой проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это будет происходить автоматически (вы же его наследуете) :) Ничего делать не нужно.

Comment: Нет у меня там ошибка вылетает

Comment: Нажмите правой кнопкой мыши, затем "Посмотреть исходный код". Найдите там свою форму и проверьте чтобы внутри был этот hidden input. Если его там не будет, значит смотрите settings.py в раздел middleware.

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

Answer (score 0):

Если я не ошибаюсь, шаблон обращается к форме авторизации, а в форме авторизации, я так понимаю во `view` можно дописать в `return render_to_response(..., context_instance=RequestContext(request))`
соответствующий импорт: `from django.template import RequestContext`

Ну то есть, вы в общем всё правильно сделали. шаблон авторизации рендерит определённый `view`, а `view` должен возвращать `RequestContext(request)`, а шаблон запрашивает токен уже через `{% csrf_token %}`